# Pandas Dataframe - Compare values and find mismatch in each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

i have a df for product price having columns: SKU, Amazon, eBay, Walmart, PS, SPL where values can be null or Price for that SKU.

I want to compare PS and SPL if they are non-null then price should match on each row. that means, mismatch is an error SKU.

Same with Amazon, eBay, Walmart columns. Any either null or matching price is accepted.

I don’t have much knowledge in dataframe. I could do it in spreadsheet like adding a helper column with max or min of Amazon, eBay and Walmart. then comparing each value with that max or min. if all matches then good, of does not match then error SKU

What is the convenient way to find error SKUs? Is there anyone who can explain the steps as well.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Could you provide a sample table as an example and the expected result?

Comment: For future reference: Do post an xample of your data and what you've tried. Also, be more precise in the rules you want to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simpl way of doing this is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'SKU': ['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004'], 
                   'Amazon': [10, 20, 30, None],
                   'eBay': [10, 30, 40, None],
                   'Walmart': [None, 20, 30, 40],
                   'PS': [10, None, 30, 40],
                   'SPL': [20, None, 30, 40]})

df['max_min_price'] = df[['Amazon', 'eBay', 'Walmart']].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().max() if len(x.dropna())>0 else None, axis=1)
df['PS_SPL_error'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Error' if (x['PS'] is not None and x['SPL'] is not None and x['PS'] != x['SPL']) else 'OK', axis=1)
df['Amazon_eBay_Walmart_error'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Error' if (x['Amazon'] is not None and x['eBay'] is not None and x['Walmart'] is not None and x['max_min_price'] is not None and x['max_min_price'] != x['Amazon'] and x['max_min_price'] != x['eBay'] and x['max_min_price'] != x['Walmart']) else 'OK', axis=1)
df['Overall_error'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Error' if (x['PS_SPL_error'] == 'Error' or x['Amazon_eBay_Walmart_error'] == 'Error') else 'OK', axis=1)

print(df)
```

which gives you

```
    SKU  Amazon  eBay  Walmart    PS   SPL  max_min_price PS_SPL_error  \
0  1001    10.0  10.0      NaN  10.0  20.0           10.0        Error   
1  1002    20.0  30.0     20.0   NaN   NaN           30.0        Error   
2  1003    30.0  40.0     30.0  30.0  30.0           40.0           OK   
3  1004     NaN   NaN     40.0  40.0  40.0           40.0           OK   

  Amazon_eBay_Walmart_error Overall_error  
0                        OK         Error  
1                        OK         Error  
2                        OK            OK  
3                        OK            OK
```